# How can I play an audio stream with an internet URL on current Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-10, audio, streaming, windows-media-player, audio-streaming

I'm sure that I used to listen to audio streams with Media Player in the past.

Now in July 2017 I can't find any way to get it to play from a URL.

In fact I can't even find anything in the GUI to get the version number!

However, some of the options mention internet audio streams.

Has this functionality been removed? If not, where is it hiding?

(I'm running 32-bit Windows 10.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to Murphy's Law, after not being able to find an answer to this for some months, I find it one minute after finally posting the question here!

Media Player has an invisible menu. At least it's invisible on my system.

But it will appear when you press the Alt key.

File menu:
[image: Windows Media Player "File" menu]

File/Open URL... menu item
[image: Windows Media Player "File/Open URL" menu item]

Open URL dialog box
[image: Windows Media Player "Open URL" dialog box]

Answer (score 1):

You get the same result when you paste the mms url into Chrome, it offers to open an external app, you chose Windows Media Player.